# RATING TRIGGER IF RATING IS MORE THAN 5 THROW ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create sql trigger if rating is more than 5 throw error

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER RATING_VALUE
BEFORE INSERT ON HOC_Reviews
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.rating > 5 THEN
        RAISERROR( "You can rate only from 1 to 5");
    END IF;
END;/
```

Comment: add a check constrait to rating it costs less performace and does  the same

Comment: `if then end if` is not a valid `if` statement in sql. Use `if begin end`.

Comment: See also the concept of a table check constraint, where the column can be restricted directly: ... `CHECK (colname BETWEEN 1 AND 5)`.  Here's a small example: `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c468fa34f48c57434b577f8c51635549`

Comment: What happens when you try the code you've shown? Do you get an error message? Is there something in the error message you don't understand? Please [edit] your question and be more specific.

Comment: SQL Server does not have `BEFORE` or `FOR EACH ROW` in triggers, has different order of the clauses and does not have `IF/THEN`. The only thing SQL Server has from this code is the `RAISERROR`, but even then it is missing the required severity and state.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message.

Comment: And also check if you are REALLY using `sql-server`.  Tell us the return value for `select @@version;`

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/840849/rating-trigger.html)

Answer (score 2):

A trigger is not the way; use `check`:

```
create table HOC_Reviews (
    -- other columns
    rating int not null check (rating between 1 and 5),
    -- other columnS
)
```

Note the ease of reading when the check is coded using `between` and the implicit check for `rating >= 1` being included, which you should also be making if you're checking `rating <= 5`.